# How to set gallery custom field to slick slide container

Tags: php

I am trying to assign a custom field gallery image as a background image on a slick slide wrap.

```
        foreach ($gallery_image_ids as $gallery_image_id ) {
         $slides .= "<div class='slick-slide-wrap' >";
         $slides .= wp_get_attachment_image( $gallery_image_id, 'large');
         $slides .= "</div>";
        }
```

I have been able to set it using an image tag. However, I'd like to be able to set it as a background image on the container above, but it keeps erroring when I have tried the following code below.

```
    $test = wp_get_attachment_url( $gallery_image_id, 'large');
    foreach ($gallery_image_ids as $gallery_image_id ) {
        $slides .= "<div class='slick-slide-wrap' background-image: url(' .$test. ')>";
        $slides .= wp_get_attachment_image( $gallery_image_id, 'large');
        $slides .= "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: "it keeps erroring" - what does that mean? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an HTML problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_get_attachment_image` you're using returns an HTML img element.

What you need is `wp_get_attachment_image_url` which returns the image URL: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/

```
$slides .= '<div class="slick-slide-wrap" style="background-image: url(' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $gallery_image_id, 'large') . ');">';
```